# I'm having some trouble disabling options in a materialize select

Tags: javascript, materialize, dom-manipulation

This is very similar to one of my other questions, but this time, there is no html. I created the select using Javascript DOM manipulation, and that same answer doesn't work. I am trying to disable one option in a materialize select, using javascript, but it just doesn't work.

```
let securitySelect = document.createElement('select');
    let securityOptionWebmaster = document.createElement('option');
    securityOptionWebmaster.textContent = 'Webmaster';
    securityOptionWebmaster.setAttribute('value', '1');
    securitySelect.appendChild(securityOptionWebmaster);
```

(more select options added here)

```
let security;
    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid);
    docRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        security = doc.data().security;
        if (security == '2') {
            securityOptionWebmaster.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you done basic debugging? Does your `if` condition actually get called? Put a `console.log()` inside it to confirm.

Comment: Ok. Done. The console.log works, so It does get called.

Comment: But the `option` definitely doesn't get the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can still select that just like any other option. If this information helps: this is within a materialize table. I use a forEach method when calling the function so that it creates a different row for each user. Each row has its own select. What this code should do is get the data for the current user, and then disable the option in every row.

Comment: Have you forgot `M.FormSelect.init(securitySelect);` again?

Comment: Recently, I asked a question similar to this one, and got the answer, but that same answer doesn't work on this one.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160856/how-can-i-dynamically-update-materialize-select/66163235#66163235

Comment: I have already added that right below the code snippet shown. I used     M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));

Comment: @RayBeard well you didn't add in your question so I assume you forgot lol. Maybe there are many `select` in your webpage and `document.querySelectorAll('select')` return list of DOM so it didn't work

Comment: I tried initializeing it with the variable instead of the queryselector, and I got this error in the console(from materialize.min.js 6): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Comment: I figured it out. I should have placed the initialization inside the function.‍♂️