# Asp.Net MVC After Creating Cascade, The Dropdown function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to create cascade dropdown list controls and the values are returned correctly, however, the dropdown functionality doesn't work. I believe it's because there are no values added to the select-options section and I don't know how to do it.
[image: Dropdown HTML code]

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <label asp-for="KPI.Value" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="KPI.Value" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="KPI.Value" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <select id="CriteriasList" asp-for="KPI.CriteriaID" asp-items="ViewBag.Criteria" onchange="onCriteriaChange()">
                </select>
                <label>Criteria</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field" style="display:none" id="employees">
                <select id="EmployeesList" asp-for="KPI.Employee" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "GID", "FullName"))">
                </select>
                <label>Employee</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').formSelect();
});

function onCriteriaChange() {
    var criteriaID = document.getElementById("CriteriasList").value;
    var criterias = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Criterias));

    for (var i = 0; i < criterias.length; i++)
    {
        if (criterias[i].id == criteriaID)
        {
            if (criterias[i].isIndividual)
            {
                $.get("/KPIs/GetFilteredUsers",
                    {
                        critID: $("#CriteriasList").val()
                    },
                    function (result)
                    {
                        $("#EmployeesList").empty();

                        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                            $("#EmployeesList").append("<option value='" + item.value + "'>" + item.text + "</option>");
                        });

                    });
                
                document.getElementById('employees').style.display = "block";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('employees').style.display = "none";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using an unspecified `select` wrapper (materialize?).  It's likely that *this* wrapper needs to be refreshed/updated/re-initialised when you change the `select` `option`s as otherwise how would it know?   Remove this line `$('select').formSelect();` and see if your ajax code works, so you can target your debugging/fix in the correct place.

Comment: *Possible* solution, depending on the specifics of the `select` wrapper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163235/2181514